# Subsetting dataframe where values change

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to filter rows from a `data.frame` based on where the values change.
Suppose I have:

```
    id  name  quarter      score      
1.  01  john  q1 2020      80
2.  01  john  q2 2020      80
3.  01  john  q3 2020      85
4.  01  john  q4 2020      75
5.  02  adam  q1 2020      80
6.  02  adam  q2 2020      80
7.  02  adam  q3 2020      85
8.  03  lana  q1 2020      50
```

Wherever the quarter and score both change, I want to filter out those rows. So the data frame above should become,

```
    id  name  quarter      score      
1.  01  john  q2 2020      80
2.  01  john  q3 2020      85
3.  01  john  q4 2020      75
4.  02  adam  q2 2020      80
5.  02  adam  q3 2020      85
```

How do I compare the value of a cell with the value in the previous row in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lead` function from `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>% filter(quarter != lead(quarter), score != lead(score))
result
#   id name quarter score
#2.  1 john  q22020    80
#3.  1 john  q32020    85
#4.  1 john  q42020    75
#6.  2 adam  q22020    80
#7.  2 adam  q32020    85
```

and similarly in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[quarter != shift(quarter, type = 'lead') & 
          score != lead(score, type = 'lead')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `subset` + `ave` like below

```
subset(
  df,
  !!ave(score,id,FUN = function(x) c(TRUE,diff(x)!=0)&length(x)>1)
)
```

which gives

```
  id name quarter score
1  1 john q1_2020    80
3  1 john q3_2020    85
4  1 john q4_2020    75
5  2 adam q1_2020    80
7  2 adam q3_2020    85
```

**data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), name = c("john", 
"john", "john", "john", "adam", "adam", "adam", "lana"), quarter = c("q1_2020", 
"q2_2020", "q3_2020", "q4_2020", "q1_2020", "q2_2020", "q3_2020", 
"q1_2020"), score = c(80L, 80L, 85L, 75L, 80L, 80L, 85L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```